# make_unique vs make_shared

Tags: ros, ros2, shared-ptr

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

In the TF2 listener tutorial (c++), the buffer is defined as a `std::unique_ptr` whereas the listener is a `std::shared_ptr`.

```
tf_buffer_ = std::make_unique<tf2_ros::Buffer>(this->get_clock());
tf_listener_ = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::TransformListener>(*tf_buffer_);
```

Is this intentional? I.e. is there a specific reason for the listener to be a `std::shared_ptr`, or could it just as well also have been a `std::unique_ptr`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409751/make_unique-vs-make_shared/) by [jrtg](https://answers.ros.org/users/124778/jrtg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2022-11-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am not sure it matters a lot.
Actually when using tf inside a node you can also not use pointers at all. You just have to initialize the constructors of buffer and listener in the member initializer list.

```
class MyNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    MyNode(rclcpp::NodeOptions options)
        : Node("the_name", options), tf_buffer(get_clock()), tf_listener(tf_buffer)
    {
    // constructor
    }

private:

// TF 2 stuff
tf2_ros::Buffer tf_buffer; // order matters, buffer has to be built before listener
tf2_ros::TransformListener tf_listener;

}
```

You can even do it in the member variable declaration:

```
class MyNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    MyNode(rclcpp::NodeOptions options)
        : Node("the_name", options)
    {
    // constructor
    }

private:

// TF 2 stuff
tf2_ros::Buffer tf_buffer{get_clock()};
tf2_ros::TransformListener tf_listener{tf_buffer};

}
```

---

Originally posted by [Olivier Kermorgant](https://answers.ros.org/users/11856/olivier-kermorgant/) with karma: 280 on 2023-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure, but I think it's intentional, as [in this tutorial (docs.ros.org/en/humble)](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Intermediate/Tf2/Writing-A-Tf2-Listener-Cpp.html) `tf2_ros::Buffer` is meant to be only accessed by `tf2_ros::TransformListener` (and assume it doesn't increase reference counter in its internal logic) while `tf_listener_` can potentially be accessed many times.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2023-06-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jrtg](https://answers.ros.org/users/124778/jrtg/) on 2023-06-02**:
Yes, that could be the reasoning, yet it isn't a strict necessity. To me (coming from c++98 and being new to ROS) it was rather confusing.